# Appium Inspector not able distinguish widgets inside Stack widget in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, automation, appium

When clickable widgets are placed inside Stack widget in flutter application then Appium inspector is not able to inspect this widgets which are inside stacked widget.
It considers all this widgets as single widget.

Here is the screen shot of appium inspector containing xPath where it shows skip_app_review and description text as single path however this 2 are different.

[image]

Anyone can give any suggestion how to get individual widgets xPath in appium inspector if used inside stack widget.